# Which is correct - "What is the difference between these two words?" or "What are the differences between these two words?"

Tags: singular-vs-plural

I would like to know which sentence among below is correct and how one is different than one another.

> What **is the difference** between these two words?
>
> What **are the differences** between these two words?

Comment: What do you think the difference(s) could be? Think about the difference between singular and plural.

Comment: In context, how many differences are you expecting?

Comment: The difference can be one, two or more. And frankly, I don't believe it is not the same thing in your native language. One difference, two differences. Tell me your language doesn't distinguish that? I would close this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both can be correct, depending on the words.  You may expect more than one *difference*.  For example:

> What is the difference between a "smuggler" and a "pirate"?

(I assume that these words are very similar, and there is only a small difference.)

> What are the differences between a "smuggler" and a "pirate"?

(I assume that these are different enough that there are multiple differences.)

It doesn't necessarily matter how many things are actually different, only how many you *expect*.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer! But normally as a foreign student learning English, when I ask a native English speaking teacher a question about  how __expect__ and __anticipate__ are different, which would be more proper?

Comment: Good question!  I *expect* that "expect and "anticipate" are very similar, so I would ask "What is the *difference* between expect and anticipate?"